# GridView only lists first image in directory

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to display all images in a certain directory in a GridView, but only the first image is being displayed. Here is what I'm using:

In onCreate:

```
iconGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.iconGrid);
getImageFiles();
iconGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

getImageFiles():

```
public void getImageFiles() {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "img");
    if (dir.isDirectory())
        for (File f : dir.listFiles())
            for (String ext : IMAGE_EXTENSIONS)
                if (f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) {
                    Log.d(f.toString(), "Adding file");
                    files.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
}
```

imageAdapter()

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount () {
        return files.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("", "Getting image " + files.get(position).toString());
        ImageView c;
        if (convertView == null) {
            c = new ImageView(context);

            c.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 160));
            c.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            c.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        } else {
            c = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files.get(position));
        c.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        return c;
    }
}
```

With the logging in place, it seems that getView() is never called for positions that aren't 0, and each file is being added to the list, with the list size being the correct number of files. Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was being added to GridView, it just wasn't visible without scrolling down and changing the number of columns.